# Expired patent with pending continuation applications and appeals on those

Tags: expiration, continuation

When a patent expires due to non-payment what happens to pending child continuation applications and an appeal of a child continuation application?  I assume the expire patent is not valid at least while expired so there would be nothing for the applications to tie to.  Will the PTO still consider the application from a couple of years ago and an appeal of an application from several years ago?

Answer (score 2):

Child applications / patents are separate issues. They do not share procedures. So the answer is simply: It doesn't matter if the parent expired, lapsedor got invalidated.

Comment: I agree. However, I wonder if you might be able to add some references for posterity's sake? I assume there's something salient in the MPEP on it, though I haven't looked.